# terminal command doesn't work in java

Tags: java, macos, terminal, command

I am trying to execute a terminal command (includes a jar file) in a jsp application.
The command works fine when I execute it in the terminal. But when I use it in java, I get an error specific to the program I am trying to execute, which means I can access to the folder, run it but there is somehow a syntax error or I am missing something.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar /AbsoluteFilePath/rdfslice_1.42.jar"+
" -source /AbsoluteFilePath/test.nt"+
" -patterns \"{?s ?p ?o}\" -out /AbsoluteFilePath/output.out" +
" -order \"S\" -debug -debugGraphSize 1024");

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    builder.append(line);
    builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}
String result = builder.toString();
System.out.println(result);
```

I also tried process builder but did not yield any different results.
Code I tried for the process builder was :

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(
                "java",
                "-jar",
                "/AbsoluteFilePath/rdfslice_1.42.jar",
                "-source",
                "/AbsoluteFilePath/test.nt",
                "-pattern", "'{?s ?p ?o}'", "-out",
                "/AbsoluteFilePath/output.out",
                "-order", "'S'" );

        // create the process builder
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(list);


Process p = pb.start();
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Regards

Comment: Can you show the error that you're getting?

Comment: Using an absolute path for "java"? - I'd still like to see that error message and the shell command that works.

Comment: Directly from terminal : 
java -jar /AbsolutePath/rdfslice_1.42.jar -source /AbsolutePath/rdfslice/test.nt -patterns "{?s ?p ?o}" -out /AbsolutePath/rdfslice/eclipse.out -order "S"

Comment: the error message is application specific 
http://cl.ly/image/2Q1y3w11380B

Comment: @emrahozkan Yes, this indicates that argument passing is broken. See updated answer.

Comment: processbuilder works the way you mention, I have also tried it. by the way I think getruntime().exec() takes whole string as argument.

Answer (score 2):

If it would go through a shell, spacing is essential.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar /AbsoluteFilePath/rdfslice_1.42.jar"+
    " -source /AbsoluteFilePath/test.nt"+ 
    " -patterns \"{?s ?p ?o}\" -out /AbsoluteFilePath/output.out" +
    " -order \"S\" -debug -debugGraphSize 1024");
```

Note the spaces in front of the continuation lines.

This isn't going through the shell, so arguments have to be provided as individual strings.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java", "-jar",
         "/AbsoluteFilePath/rdfslice_1.42.jar",
         "-source",  "/AbsoluteFilePath/test.nt",
         "-patterns", "{?s ?p ?o}",
         "-out", "/AbsoluteFilePath/output.out",
         "-order", "S", "-debug2", "-debugGraphSize", "1024");
```

Comment: thanks but actually it was in one line, I changed it into this form for readability.